# How do I display the content of React Quill without the html markup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill

I managed to get my Quill working, but now I wanted to make a nice splitscreen as we have on this forum but one thing I haven't been able to figure out is how to convert the input of Quill to nice text on the preview side.

I'm able to display the text but it still has all the html tags which of course I don't want.

So this is my Quill setup so far:

```js
export default class AddSpark extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);

    this.state ={
      content: '',
    };
  }

  onChange(html) {
    this.setState ({ content: html });
      console.log(html)
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Col xs={12} md={6}>
        <form ref={(input) => this.sparkForm = input} onSubmit={(e) => this.createSpark(e)}>

            <ControlLabel>Select your city</ControlLabel>
            <select id="formControlsCity" placeholder="Choose your city" onChange={this.onChange} className="form-control" onClick={ moreOptions } ref={(input) => this.city = input}>
              <option value="select">Choose your city</option>
              <option value="Beijing">Beijing</option>
              <option value="Shanghai">Shanghai</option>
              <option value="Chengdu & Chongqing">Chengdu & Chongqing</option>
            </select>
       
            <ControlLabel>Select your person</ControlLabel>
            <select id="formControlsPerson" placeholder="Choose your person" className="form-control" ref={(input) => this.person = input}>
              <option value="select">First select your city</option>
            </select>
    

            <ControlLabel>Select your location</ControlLabel>
            <select id="formControlsLocation" placeholder="Choose your location" className="form-control" ref={(input) => this.location = input}>
              <option value="select">First select your city</option>
            </select>

            <ControlLabel>Title</ControlLabel>
            <input type="text" label="Title" placeholder="Enter your title" className="form-control" ref={(input) => this.title = input}/>
          

            <ControlLabel>Content</ControlLabel>
              <div className='_quill'>
                <ReactQuill
                  ref='editor'
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </div>
              <br />

          <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
        </form>
      </Col>
      <Col xs={12} md={6}>
      <h3>Preview</h3>
        {this.state.content}
      </Col>

      </div>
  )}
}
```

At the moment I get this: 
[image]

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After doing some research I was able to find the answer:

To display the content of Quill in the preview section without the html tags I used this code:

```html
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.content}}></div>
```

Comment: How about the CSS style? There're some classes in the HTML codes, not inline-style.

Comment: Just add the "ql-editor" classname then, like explained here: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/3193#issuecomment-1954938850

Answer (score 37):

The simplest way is to use the same react-quill component with editing disabled. **This method doesn't need you to install any extra package.** You can do it by passing a prop readOnly whose value is set to true (By default it is false)

Here is the code for the component which you can use to preview side:

```
<ReactQuill
   value={this.state.content}
   readOnly={true}
   theme={"bubble"}
/>
```

This is how it will look like:
[image: sample image]

**Note:** ReactQuill comes with two inbuilt themes (bubble and snow).

Here is how it looks in the **snow theme**. It has a toolbar at the top:
[image: bubble]

And here is how it looks in **bubble theme**.
[image: snow theme]

You should use the "bubble" theme by passing the string "bubble" in the theme prop to display your editor content. This is because it does not have a toolbar at the top like the "snow" theme.

In order to use the bubble theme, you'll also have to [import a CSS stylesheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-quill) for this specific theme as follow:*

```
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.bubble.css'
```

Comment: I think currently this is the best solution to display editor's content outside the editor context. What a shame that you are forced to use hacks to display editor's content. Isn't it the main purpose of the editor - to generate content that can later be displayed somewhere outside the editor's context?

Comment: Thank you @Salivan 
Yes, you are right. Why should we use any hacks to display the editor's content if the editor already has a built-in way to display the content. It is a safer and straight forward solution.

Comment: Brilliant! Proves that programming is so much more than just syntax! thank you thank you!

Answer (score 14):

```
onChange(content, delta, source, editor) {
  const text = editor.getText(content);
  this.setState ({ content: text });
  console.log(text)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You need html-react-parser

```
import Parser from 'html-react-parser';

...     // in your render
<ReactQuill
    ...
    value={code} 
    onChange={this.previewCode}
/>
...
{Parser(code)}
```

Answer (score 5):

i used it like this in React.js..
To display quil content in a div i use class "ql-editor" because through this our div can use the quil default classes...works..

```
import ReactQuill from "react-quill";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";

const ReactMarkdown = require("react-markdown/with-html"); //for displaying html

function editorContent() {
  <div className="ql-editor" style={{ padding: 0 }}>
        <ReactMarkdown escapeHtml={false} source={quilGeneratedHtml} />
  </div>
}
```

Comment: @M Shahzaib Shoaib thanks, this class thing did my work ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here's the docs link: https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill#the-unprivileged-editor

simple to implement and getText out of quill editor

```js
// define function to get text, 
// here inpText is defined in your constructor, or any global variable
onChangeText = () => {
    const editor = this.reactQuillRef.getEditor();
    const unprivilegedEditor = this.reactQuillRef.makeUnprivilegedEditor(editor);
    // You may now use the unprivilegedEditor proxy methods
    this.inpText = unprivilegedEditor.getText();
        console.log("unprivilegedEditor.getText()", unprivilegedEditor.getText());
    }

    // on submit, you can set state with that text binded in this.inpText
    this.setState({text: this.inputText})
}

// define react quill component
<ReactQuill value={this.state.text} onChange={this.onChangeText} ref={(el) => { this.reactQuillRef = el }} />
```

Good Luck...

Answer (score 2):

To preview HTML in your web page in **REACT** then there are 2 options you have,

1. using dependency [**html-react-parser**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser)
   Follow below steps,
   **Step1:**
   Install dependency using below command,
   npm i html-react-parser
   If you are using **yarn** then use below command,
   yarn add html-react-parser

   **Step 2:**

   ```
   const parse = require('html-react-parser');
   parse(`<div>${this.state.content}</div>`);
   ```
2. Use below code to set the editor contents using below code,

   ```
     <div
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: this.state.content,
     }}
   ```

   > 

Answer (score 1):

Using 'html-react-parser' worked for me

Comment: Consider posting this as a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you save data from an editor like Quill to a database and then retrieve it, you will sometimes have problems with the encoded HTML stored in the database. This usually happens when HTML is understood and processed in the context database.

**1. Using `npm i react-html-parser` install [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser):**

```
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';

   <p>{ ReactHtmlParser(quillContent) }</p>
```

**2. Use dangerouslySetInnerHTML:**

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: quillContent }} />
```

Example *`Use dangerouslySetInnerHTML`*:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Save the html output from quill editor. Then render it as an innerHTML on a div. Give class="ql-editor" to the div and the html will be formatted as we see it in the editor. No need to instantiate editor context. Just import quill's css file.

Vue example:

```
import '@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.snow.css';

<div class="ql-editor" v-html="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using 2 options:-

```
1> Using **dangerouslySetInnerHTML**, but this I will not recommend.
2> WE can try using a npm package for react such as
**html-react-parser**. Try it out, as its easy to use.
```